# Ruby on Rails: Heroku: How do I get my gems installed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

this is my GemFile

```
source :rubygems
gem 'rails', '2.3.8'
gem 'authlogic', '2.1.6'
gem 'addresslogic', '1.2.1'
gem 'searchlogic', '2.4.19'
gem 'subdomain-fu', '0.5.4'
```

but, when I run the app on heroku, I get "App Crashed"

and the log says I only have rails installed, and I need the non-rails gems listed above.

What am I doing wrong?

output from heroku push

```
     % git push heroku master
Counting objects: 10, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 860 bytes, done.
Total 6 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Rails app detected
-----> WARNING: Detected Rails is not declared in either .gems or Gemfile
       Scheduling the install of Rails 2.3.8.
       See http://docs.heroku.com/gems for details on specifying gems.

-----> Installing gem rails 2.3.8 from http://rubygems.org
       Successfully installed activesupport-2.3.8
       Successfully installed activerecord-2.3.8
       Successfully installed rack-1.1.0
       Successfully installed actionpack-2.3.8
       Successfully installed actionmailer-2.3.8
       Successfully installed activeresource-2.3.8
       Successfully installed rails-2.3.8
       7 gems installed

       Compiled slug size is 11.7MB
-----> Launching.... done
       http://%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%.heroku.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%.git
   3ac597d..b849480  master -> master
```

heroku log

```
==> dyno-3334279.log <==
Missing these required gems:
  authlogic  
  addresslogic  
  searchlogic  

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.7.253 at /usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/ruby
  rubygems 1.3.7 at /home/slugs/362612_b849480_24ac-7763f7d7-8c04-478b-ab13-af81efd3e8c2/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8, /home/slugs/362612_b849480_24ac-7763f7d7-8c04-478b-ab13-af81efd3e8c2/mnt/.bundle/gems, /home/slugs/362612_b849480_24ac-7763f7d7-8c04-478b-ab13-af81efd3e8c2/mnt/.gems, /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.

==> production.log <==
# Logfile created on Sun Nov 28 19:41:39 -0800 2010
```

Comment: Are you using Rails 3 and the Bamboo stack (recently made the default)? It'd also be helpful to see the console output from pushing to Heroku, and the actual output of the log file.

Comment: Well... I want to use 2.3.8. Don't know anything about bamboo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a file named `Gemfile` (in this exact case/spelling) in the root of your repository, Heroku will use this file to determine all the gems to install.

You mentioned that you have a `GemFile` - if that is the way the filename is cased in your repository, Heroku may not pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a file called .gems in your application root. That file should contain a list of the gems you need and the syntax for defining the gem dependencies are like this:

```
rails --version 2.3.8
authlogic --version 2.1.6
```

etc...

Comment: Okay. Has been a few months since I did this myself and I know it worked then.